# Calculating distance to 200m depth in bathymetric raster layer using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, distance, bathymetry

I have a bathymetry layer and I would like to be able to calculate the distance to the 200m depth in the bathymetry raster in arcmap 10.2.

How would I go about this?

I've tried the Euclidian distance tool but it did not come out as expected and there were many NA.

Comment: Horizontal or vertical or nearest? Are both rasters?

Comment: Sorry it is just the bathymetric raster and I would like to calculate horizontal distance from where the ocean is 200m deep

Comment: @Jean
Hello, can you please share the complete procedure you did to get the desired results for above mentioned problem.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need [contour](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/contour.htm) instrument. `Only available with 3D Analyst license.` 
Contour is used to create a polyline feature dataset from an input raster. More details see [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-contouring-works.htm).

Comment: Thank you so much, I managed to get spatial analyst and it works well.